# Error C2664 compiling DLL based on old crypto++ library

Tags: c++, dll, crypto++, c2664

I'm not a C++ programmer and i'm just trying to compile an old DLL (VS6 I think) in VS2010 based on the crypto++ library for the purpose of debugging it to find out how it works as I have to write some code in another language to be able to read things it encrypts

When I try to compile the DLL I get Error C2664 on the first typename in this bit of code

```
 #else /* _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 0 */
    _Vector_val(_Alloc _Al = _Alloc())
        : _Alval(_Al)
        {   // construct allocator from _Al
        typename _Alloc::template rebind<_Container_proxy>::other
            _Alproxy(_Alval);
        this->_Myproxy = _Alproxy.allocate(1);
        _Cons_val(_Alproxy, this->_Myproxy, _Container_proxy());
        this->_Myproxy->_Mycont = this;

        _Myfirst = 0;
        _Mylast = 0;
        _Myend = 0;
        }

    ~_Vector_val()
        {   // destroy proxy
        typename _Alloc::template rebind<_Container_proxy>::other
            _Alproxy(_Alval);
        this->_Orphan_all();
        _Dest_val(_Alproxy, this->_Myproxy);
        _Alproxy.deallocate(this->_Myproxy, 1);
        this->_Myproxy = 0;
        }
 #endif /* _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 0 */
```

I've had a Google but I don't understand enough about the answer to be able to change it

The actual error shown in the build is this

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\vector(441): error C2664: 'CryptoPP::AllocatorWithCleanup<T>::AllocatorWithCleanup(const CryptoPP::AllocatorWithCleanup<T> &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'CryptoPP::AllocatorWithCleanup<T>' to 'const CryptoPP::AllocatorWithCleanup<T> &'
```

But i'm not sure how that relates to the line it points to when I double click as I cant seem to find any of the words it uses ?

Thanks very much in advance for your time and assistance

PS I darn't look at a newer version of the library that probably would compile as I wont know if they have changed any of the encryption methods used

Here is the full contents of the output window

```
1>------ Build started: Project: dfxext, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  StdAfx.cpp
1>  _WIN32_WINNT not defined. Defaulting to _WIN32_WINNT_MAXVER (see WinSDKVer.h)
1>  CDialogSK.cpp
1>  CMSDialog.cpp
1>  CtlStockIcon.cpp
1>  DonorflexDLL.cpp
1>c:\users\andrew.cmac\documents\temp c++ project search\common\c++\agk_vs2010_dfxext\donorflexdll.cpp(63): warning C4996: 'CWinApp::SetDialogBkColor': CWinApp::SetDialogBkColor is no longer supported. Instead, handle WM_CTLCOLORDLG in your dialog
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\atlmfc\include\afxwin.h(5365) : see declaration of 'CWinApp::SetDialogBkColor'
1>  DonProgress.cpp
1>  EnterpriseRegistrationDialog.cpp
1>  GradientFillBox.cpp
1>  interfaces.cpp
1>c:\users\andrew.cmac\documents\temp c++ project search\common\c++\agk_vs2010_dfxext\interfaces.cpp(308): warning C4996: 'strcpy': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strcpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\string.h(105) : see declaration of 'strcpy'
1>c:\users\andrew.cmac\documents\temp c++ project search\common\c++\agk_vs2010_dfxext\interfaces.cpp(508): warning C4996: 'strncpy': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strncpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\string.h(188) : see declaration of 'strncpy'
1>c:\users\andrew.cmac\documents\temp c++ project search\common\c++\agk_vs2010_dfxext\interfaces.cpp(538): warning C4996: 'strncpy': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strncpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\string.h(188) : see declaration of 'strncpy'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\vector(441): error C2664: 'CryptoPP::AllocatorWithCleanup<T>::AllocatorWithCleanup(const CryptoPP::AllocatorWithCleanup<T> &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'CryptoPP::AllocatorWithCleanup<T>' to 'const CryptoPP::AllocatorWithCleanup<T> &'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=std::_Container_proxy
1>          ]
1>          and
1>          [
1>              T=CryptoPP::HuffmanDecoder::CodeInfo
1>          ]
1>          and
1>          [
1>              T=std::_Container_proxy
1>          ]
1>          Reason: cannot convert from 'CryptoPP::AllocatorWithCleanup<T>' to 'const CryptoPP::AllocatorWithCleanup<T>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=CryptoPP::HuffmanDecoder::CodeInfo
1>          ]
1>          and
1>          [
1>              T=std::_Container_proxy
1>          ]
1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\vector(437) : while compiling class template member function 'std::_Vector_val<_Ty,_Alloc>::_Vector_val(_Alloc)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=CryptoPP::HuffmanDecoder::CodeInfo,
1>              _Alloc=CryptoPP::AllocatorWithCleanup<CryptoPP::HuffmanDecoder::CodeInfo>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\vector(481) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Vector_val<_Ty,_Alloc>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=CryptoPP::HuffmanDecoder::CodeInfo,
1>              _Alloc=CryptoPP::AllocatorWithCleanup<CryptoPP::HuffmanDecoder::CodeInfo>
1>          ]
1>          c:\users\andrew.cmac\documents\temp c++ project search\common\c++\libcrypto\zinflate.h(79) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::vector<_Ty,_Ax>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=CryptoPP::HuffmanDecoder::CodeInfo,
1>              _Ax=CryptoPP::AllocatorWithCleanup<CryptoPP::HuffmanDecoder::CodeInfo>
1>          ]
1>  MD5Checksum.cpp
1>  ProgressDialog.cpp
1>  SmallProgressDialog.cpp
1>  SplashScreen.cpp
1>  SplashScreenIdleThread.cpp
1>  Generating Code...
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

The only references to the text 'max_size' in the whole libraray are these and they ar all in a file called secblock.h

```
size_type max_size() const {return ~size_type(0)/sizeof(T);}    // switch to std::numeric_limits<T>::max later
size_type max_size() const {return 0;}
size_type max_size() const {return STDMAX(m_fallbackAllocator.max_size(), S);}
```

This is the interfaces.cpp file. Hopefully that is what you meant

```
// DonorflexDLL.cpp : Defines the initialization routines for the DLL.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "constants.h"
#include "interfaces.h"

#include "DonProgress.h"

#include "..\libzipproxy\zipproxy.h"

#include "MD5Checksum.h"
#include "GradientFillBox.h"

#include <NamedPipeClient.h>
#include <PCREWrapper.h>

#include "EnterpriseRegistrationDialog.h"

#include "SplashScreen.h"
#include "SplashScreenIdleThread.h"

#include <InstanceManagerClient.h>

// Headers to support cryptography:
#include <string>       // STL
#include <default.h>    // Crypto++ libraries.
#include <hex.h>        // Hex Encoders and Decords from CryptoPP
#include <base64.h>     // base64 Encoders and Decords from CryptoPP
#include <zlib.h>       // Compression

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#undef THIS_FILE
static char THIS_FILE[] = __FILE__;
#endif

#define LIBVER 95

using namespace ui;
using namespace threads;
using namespace std;
using namespace CryptoPP;

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// CDon32App

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// CDon32App construction

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// The one and only CDon32App object

// Global functions for access from DataFlex:

UINT DFXAPI DON32_Version() {
    // Version: 1.0 01/05/1997

    // Purpose:
    // To supply the current version of the library to the Donorflex base system:

    // Local Variables:

    // Code:
    return LIBVER;  // Define globally in Don32.h
}

void DFXAPI DON32_About() {
    // Version: 1.0 01/05/1997

    // Purpose:
    // To show the Donorflex Gi About screen.

    // Local variables:

    // Code:
    // TODO
}

HIMAGELIST DFXAPI DON32_GetImageList(UINT uiWhich) {
    // Version: 1.0 01/05/1997

    // Purpose:
    // To return the handle of the standard image list.

    // Local variables:

    // Code:
    // TODO:

    // Returns:
    return NULL;
}

void DFXAPI DON32_AddBubbleMessage(LPCSTR lpszMsg, DWORD iFont) {
}

// InitBubble, resets the contents of the string arrays and font type,
// must be called before using the bubble routine.
void DFXAPI DON32_InitBubbleWindow(void) {
}

// Tip of the day support:

void DFXAPI DON32_TipAtStartup(void) {

}

void DFXAPI DON32_TipOfTheDay(void) {

}

// Progress Box Thread Control:

/*
Purpose / Description:
    This interface is historic and was imported from the original DON32 library

*/
void DFXAPI DON32_BeginProgressThread(HWND hWndParent, DWORD dwAnim, LPSTR lpsCaption, LPSTR lpsTitle, LPSTR lpsMsg, int iCancel) {
    CDonProgressThread *instance = CDonProgressThread::GetInstance(hWndParent, dwAnim, lpsCaption, lpsTitle, lpsMsg, iCancel, RGB(0,0x65,0xFF)); // TODO replace this with proper default colour.
}

void DFXAPI DFX_SmallProgress(HWND hWndParent, DWORD dwAnim, LPSTR lpsTitle, LPSTR lpsMsg) {
    CDonProgressThread *instance = CDonProgressThread::GetInstance(hWndParent, dwAnim, lpsTitle, lpsMsg);
}

/*
Description:
    New interface as of 26/01/2004 by EN to facilitate setting of theme colours
    throughout the donorflex application.
*/
void DFXAPI DFX_Progress(HWND hWndParent, DWORD dwAnim, LPSTR lpsCaption, LPSTR lpsTitle, LPSTR lpsMsg, int iCancel, COLORREF gradientColour) {
    CDonProgressThread *instance = CDonProgressThread::GetInstance(hWndParent, dwAnim, lpsCaption, lpsTitle, lpsMsg, iCancel, gradientColour);
}

void DFXAPI DON32_EndProgressThread(void) {
    CDonProgressThread *instance = CDonProgressThread::GetInstance();

    if (instance) instance->CloseInstance();
}

void DFXAPI DON32_ProgressSuspend(void) {
    // NOTE: This function is not implemeted in Donorflex.
}

// Progress Box Control:

void DFXAPI DON32_ProgressMsgA(LPSTR lpszMsg) {
    CDonProgressThread *instance = CDonProgressThread::GetInstance();

    if (instance) instance->SetDialogMessageA(lpszMsg);
}

void DFXAPI DON32_ProgressMsgB(LPSTR lpszMsg) {
    CDonProgressThread *instance = CDonProgressThread::GetInstance();

    if (instance) instance->SetDialogMessageB(lpszMsg);
}

void DFXAPI DON32_ProgressMeter(int iLow, int iHigh) {
}

void DFXAPI DON32_ProgressSet(int iPos) {
}

void DFXAPI DON32_ProgressStep() {
}

DWORD DFXAPI DON32_QueryProgress(void) {
    DWORD dword = FALSE;
    CDonProgressThread *instance = CDonProgressThread::GetInstance();

    if (instance) dword = (DWORD)instance->isCancelled();

    return dword;
}

void DFXAPI DON32_ProgressResume(void) {
    CDonProgressThread *instance = CDonProgressThread::GetInstance();

    if (instance) instance->ResetDialog();

}

void DFXAPI DON32_EnableSysTray(HWND hwndTarget) {
}

HWND DFXAPI DON32_ShowBubbleWindow(HWND hParent, DWORD bClose) {
    return NULL;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// CCMAC32App

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// CCMAC32App construction


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// The one and only CCMAC32App object

// CCMAC32App theApp;

////////////////////////////
// Globals

int DFXAPI CMAC32_GetPassword(LPCSTR lpszTitle, LPCSTR lpszValue) {
    return 0;
}

int DFXAPI CMAC32_ChangePassword(LPCSTR lpszValue, LPSTR lpszNew) {
    return 0;
}

int DFXAPI CMAC32_Dialog(DWORD wRscId) {
    return 0;
}

int DFXAPI CMAC32_SysLog(DWORD wType) {
    return 0;
}

UINT DFXAPI CMAC32_Version(void) {

    return LIBVER;
}

// New interfaces for Donorflex 6 / 9:

void DFXAPI AMO_Begin(void)
{

    // TODO Needs reworking to fit 6.1 service process architecture
}


// NEW!! Introduced for revised who's logged in processing,
// returns nonzero on success.
BOOL DFXAPI AMO_SetDetails(LPCSTR lpUserId, LPCSTR lpDetails)
{
    //client::InstanceManagerClient c;

    return false; //c.RegisterInstance(::GetCurrentProcessId(), lpUserId, NULL, lpDetails);
}

char current_user_id[24];

BOOL DFXAPI AMO_SetUserId(LPCSTR userId)
{
    //AMO_SetDetails(userId, TEXT("No Details specified"));
    //strncpy(current_user_id, userId, sizeof(current_user_id));

    return false;   // TODO
}

BOOL DFXAPI AMO_Workspace(LPCSTR lpWorkspace)
{
    // Overwrite the previous details against the current process id, based on the stored user name above.
    AMO_SetDetails(current_user_id, lpWorkspace);

    return false;   // TODO
}

BOOL DFXAPI AMO_NextMessage(LPSTR buffer)
{
    return false;   // TODO current indicates no more messages.
}

BOOL DFXAPI AMO_Broadcast(void)
{
    // TODO

    return false;
}

void DFXAPI CMS_Begin(HWND hwnd)
{

    return; // TODO
}

BOOL DFXAPI CMS_SendMessage(LPCSTR lpMsg)
{


    return false; // TODO
}

BOOL DFXAPI CMS_SendMessage2(LPCSTR lpMsg, LPCSTR lpUserName)
{
    // TODO: Support for user name passing.


    return false;
}

// MD5 interface:

BOOL DFXAPI MD5_Hash(LPCSTR lpSource, UINT nLength, LPSTR lpResult)
{
    CString result;
    LPTSTR lptResult;

    result = core::CMD5Checksum::GetMD5((BYTE*)lpSource, nLength);

    lptResult = result.LockBuffer();
    strcpy(lpResult, lptResult);
    result.UnlockBuffer();

    return FALSE;
}

BOOL DFXAPI UTL_CheckExclusive(LPCSTR sFilename)
{
    // Purpose
    // To determine whether or not a file can be open exclusively.

    // Returns:
    //  true if file can be accessed exclusively
    //  false if file cannot be accessed exclusively

    // Locals:
    CFile oFile;
    CFileException oFileException;
    BOOL bRetcode;

    // Code:
    bRetcode = oFile.Open(sFilename, CFile::modeRead|CFile::shareExclusive, &oFileException);

    return bRetcode;
}

/*
Purpose / Description:
    This interface provides a means by which a dataflex window can be
    dynamically subclassed to provide a gradient fill mechanism suitable
    for all colours and gradients.

Arguments:
    hWnd    - a handle of a window to be dynamically subclassed.
    red, green, blue - the colour.
*/
BOOL DFXAPI DFX_SubclassGradient(HWND hWnd, COLORREF col)
{
    if (CWnd::FromHandlePermanent(hWnd)) return true;

    CGradientFillBox *wnd = new CGradientFillBox(col);

    BOOL ret = wnd->SubclassWindow(hWnd);

    if (!ret) delete wnd;

    return ret;
}

/*
General purpose window subclassing.
*/
BOOL DFXAPI DFX_Subclass(HWND hWnd, int type, LPVOID lpExtra) {

/*
    if (CWnd::FromHandlePermanent(hWnd)) return true;

    // TODO CGradientFillBox *wnd = new CGradientFillBox(col);

    BOOL ret = wnd->SubclassWindow(hWnd);

    if (!ret) delete wnd;
    return ret;
*/
    return false;
}

BOOL DFXAPI DFX_Unsubclass(HWND hWnd) {

    CWnd *wnd = CWnd::FromHandlePermanent(hWnd);
    if (!wnd) return false;

    wnd->UnsubclassWindow();

    return true;
}

/*
Purpose / Description:
    This is a general purpose interface for subclassing windows
    for any type. It should be used in preference to the DFX_SubclassGradient
    function.

Arguments:
*/

/*
Purpose / Description:
    This interface allows the dataflex system to notify the subclassed window
    that a change in window colour has occured.

Arguments:
    hWnd        - The handle of the window to take the notification
    COLORREF    - The color reference that should be used from now on.

*/
BOOL DFXAPI DFX_NotifyColourChange (HWND hWnd, COLORREF col) {

    CGradientFillBox *wnd;

    // Get the window class that is mapped to this
    wnd = DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST(CGradientFillBox, CWnd::FromHandlePermanent(hWnd));

    // If the window handle is null then return the error condition:
    ASSERT(wnd);
    if (!wnd) return true;

    // Now update the COLOREF value associated with the window class:
    wnd->SetTargetColour(col);

    return false;
}

BOOL DFXAPI DFX_GradientFillDirection(HWND hWnd, int direction) {
    CGradientFillBox *wnd;

    wnd = DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST(CGradientFillBox, CWnd::FromHandlePermanent(hWnd));
    ASSERT(wnd);
    if (!wnd) return true;

    wnd->SetFillDirection(direction);

    return false;
}

// Integer value that governs if thin client mode is active or not:
int operatingmode = OM_NORMAL;

/*
Description:
    This API provides a method of switching off the animation and colour
    used in the user interactive side of the DLL.

    This is required in order to reduce bandwidth required to operate
    version 6+ of donorflex.

Assumptions & Pre-conditions:
    None

Arguments:
    mode        - Can either be 0 for standard or 1 for thin terminal services mode.
*/
int DFXAPI DFX_SetOperatingMode(int mode) {

    operatingmode = mode;

    return mode;
}

int DFXAPI DFX_GetOperatingMode() {
    return operatingmode;
}


int DFXAPI DFX_ShowSplashScreen(LPCSTR lpsFilename, COLORREF transparency, LPCSTR lpsRegName, LPCSTR lpsSerialNo, int regx, int regy, int serx, int sery)
{
    CPoint reg_point(regx, regy);
    CPoint ser_point(serx, sery);

    SplashScreenIdleThread::Show(lpsFilename, transparency, lpsRegName, lpsSerialNo, reg_point, ser_point);

    return 0;
}

int DFXAPI DFX_HideSplashScreen(HWND hwParent)
{
    SplashScreenIdleThread::Hide(hwParent);

    return 0;
}

// 13.04.2005: EN : New string encryption routine:

int DFXAPI DFX_EncryptString(const char * encoding, const char * instring, char * outstring, int outbuffsize, const char * passphrase)
{
    // Encrypts the given string buffer using the given passphrase and returns the output in the
    // buffer provided. Make sure that the size of the passed buffer is adequate.
    string ls;

    BufferedTransformation * encryptor = NULL;

    try {

        if (!strcmp(encoding, "base64")) encryptor = new DefaultEncryptorWithMAC(passphrase, new Base64Encoder(new StringSink(ls), false));
        if (!strcmp(encoding, "hex")) encryptor = new DefaultEncryptorWithMAC(passphrase, new HexEncoder(new StringSink(ls)));
        if (!strcmp(encoding, "zlib")) encryptor = new DefaultEncryptorWithMAC (passphrase, new ZlibCompressor(new StringSink(ls)));
        if (!strcmp(encoding, "none")) encryptor = new DefaultEncryptorWithMAC (passphrase, new StringSink(ls));

        encryptor->Put((byte *)instring, strlen(instring));
        encryptor->MessageEnd();
    }
    catch (...) {
        // Catch all errors
        ls = "ERROR";
    }

    // Cleanup:
    if (encryptor!=NULL) delete encryptor;

    // Copy returned string into the output buffer:
    strncpy(outstring, ls.c_str(), (size_t)outbuffsize);

    return ls.size();
}

int DFXAPI DFX_DecryptString(const char * encoding, const char * instring, char * outstring, int outbuffsize, const char * passphrase)
{
    string ls;

    BufferedTransformation * decryptor = NULL;

    try {

        if (!strcmp(encoding, "base64")) decryptor = new Base64Decoder(new DefaultDecryptorWithMAC(passphrase, new StringSink(ls)));
        if (!strcmp(encoding, "hex")) decryptor = new HexDecoder(new DefaultDecryptorWithMAC(passphrase, new StringSink(ls)));
        if (!strcmp(encoding, "zlib")) decryptor = new ZlibDecompressor (new DefaultDecryptorWithMAC(passphrase, new StringSink(ls)));
        if (!strcmp(encoding, "none")) decryptor = new DefaultDecryptorWithMAC(passphrase, new StringSink(ls));

        decryptor->Put((byte *)instring, strlen(instring));
        decryptor->MessageEnd();
    }
    catch (...) {
        // Stop any errors causing a complete mess.
        ls = "ERROR";
    }

    // Cleanup:
    if (decryptor != NULL) delete decryptor;

    // Copy returned string into the output buffer:
    strncpy(outstring, ls.c_str(), (size_t)outbuffsize);

    return ls.size();   // No error.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to update Crypto++.

Lots of google hits on this: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=crypto%2B%2B+HuffManDecoder+compile+error&oq=crypto%2B%2B+HuffManDecoder+compile+error&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8&gws_rd=ssl

Comment: Thanks but I really really don't want to have to do that. Partly because I don't really know how to swap one library for another but mainly because the code I would then be debugging would be different from that of the (old) compiled DLL i'm trying to debug to get enough information to be able to read the stuff it produces

Comment: Oh and judging by the date in our source control system I suspect i'm using version Crypto++ 5.2.1 although I don't know how to verify that

Comment: Yes just to confirm I have found the text 5.2.1 in cryptlib.h

Comment: @user3173234. Understand your reluctance: But compiling it with a different compiler will mean you're debugging different code anyway. And if you're using latest Crypto++ release with a supported compiler you'll get much more useful support from the community. 5.2.1 is over **ten** years old.

Comment: OK apart from downloading and unzipping it how would I go about swapping one library with the other in VS2010? how are they linked ? Is it just a matter of changing some project properties etc etc ?

Comment: OK I've downloaded it and managed to find the old path in the project properties Additional Include Directories .... and I now have 80 errors pasted into my main post above ....

Comment: Sorry it wouldn't fit in the main post as added to this one (which it was still too big for)

Comment: For some reason my last post was moderated out. I was trying to show 80 errors when updating to the latest library ?? I will post two in the next comment. Thanks

Comment: Error 1 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall CryptoPP::DefaultEncryptorWithMAC::DefaultEncryptorWithMAC(char const *,class CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation *)" (??0DefaultEncryptorWithMAC@CryptoPP@@QAE@PBDPAVBufferedTransformation@1@@Z) referenced in function "int __stdcall DFX_EncryptString(char const *,char const *,char *,int,char const *)" (?DFX_EncryptString@@YGHPBD0PADH0@Z) C:\Users\andrew.CMAC\Documents\Temp C++ Project Search\common\c++\AGK_VS2010_dfxext\interfaces.obj dfxext

Comment: Error 59 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall CryptoPP::DefaultDecryptorWithMAC::DefaultDecryptorWithMAC(char const *,class CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation *,bool)" (??0DefaultDecryptorWithMAC@CryptoPP@@QAE@PBDPAVBufferedTransformation@1@_N@Z) referenced in function "int __stdcall DFX_DecryptString(char const *,char const *,char *,int,char const *)" (?DFX_DecryptString@@YGHPBD0PADH0@Z) C:\Users\andrew.CMAC\Documents\Temp C++ Project Search\common\c++\AGK_VS2010_dfxext\interfaces.obj dfxext

Comment: Crypto++ will be supplied as source. You'll need to build it and then link it into your project.

Comment: Thanks. I opened the cryptopp proj, converted to VS2010, clicked on the build and it seemed to build all 4 projects in the folder. Opened the DLL project. The path to this new library is in it's project properties "Additional Include Directories". But I still get the same 80 errors ?. Thanks

Comment: Bump. Futher help would be very much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check the parameter. Seems that it is required that "first parameter template argument" (the one in "<>" braces in the parameter initialization) is allowed to be cast to type that is required.

Post more code, post code from the call stack, i cant write a more detailed answer with given information...

(Trying to guess answer...)
Maybe yours STL implementation for allocators differs from other stl implementations in code for 'max_size'. Check the 'max_size' code in the crypto++ allocator, compare it to code for standard allocator...

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. I have added the full output window to the post above. The file it is in is 2.5k like long so I would have to email that ?

Comment: Just added all references I can find to max size. Thanks

Comment: max_size seems good... can you post the user-level code that gives this error? seems that the allocators is not equal...

Comment: I've added the code for interfaces.cpp I hope that is what you meant ?